# kali headless wifi from Raspberry Pi?

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, raspberry-pi, headless

I am trying to configure a Kali install on a headless raspberry pi 4 to connect to the wifi network automagically after a reboot. I recall doing it a year or so ago and the process seemed relatively trivial. For some reason, now that I am trying it again, I can't get it to work. I've tried good'ol RTFM and multiple solutions posted on the interwebs to no avail.

Has anyone done this recently and could they outline the steps or point me to a link that does?

TIA, /mat

Additional information:

Here are some things I have tried but failed:

1. kalipi-config -> Network options (basically, raspi-config)
2. setting wpa_supplicant by hand
3. Null byte's description at: https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/set-up-headless-raspberry-pi-hacking-platform-running-kali-linux-0176182/
4. https://medium.com/@defsecone/kali-linux-installation-on-headless-raspberry-pi-1856d9c61983

One odd behavior I noticed is that if I configured wpa_supplicant.conf by hand with the wifi credentials, the raspberry pi would connect to wifi after reboot *if* it was also connected via ethernet. If I tried rebooting and disconnecting ethernet, the wifi would *not* connect.

Also, I started with a clean install each time I tried an attempt. I figured one of these should have worked.

Comment: You should describe the solutions you tried and how they failed, to avoid an answer offering the same solutions.

Comment: This seems like a request for documentation, which is off-topic here

Comment: Were you perhaps using wpa_supplicant?

Comment: I added some details and mentioned my experience with wpa_supplicant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a new Kali installation, Wi-Fi is blocked by `rfkill` if the country code is not set.

To solve that, try to obtain access to the shell and run `sudo kalipi-config`, then navigate to `04 Localisation Options -> I4 Change Wi-fi Country` and select an appropriate country.